# What is the Java "=+" operator?

Tags: java, syntax, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between += and =+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939023/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

I know what saying  x+=1; means

but what does

saying x=+1; mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `=+` operator. `x=+1` simply means assign +1 (positive 1) to `x`.

Comment: hurm It must be an odd contruct of the api I use, I assumed it was part of the Java Language because I know in C it is a post operator.

Comment: @Doodle: There is no such operator in C either. The post-increment operator is `++`, which is present in Java as well.

Answer (score 4):

It assigns a value of `+1` to variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`x += 1` can also be written as `x = x + 1`