# What is the purpose of the =+ operator in Java?

Tags: java, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between += and =+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939023/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Apparently `=+` is a valid operator. Where would you use it?

Example:

```
int j, k = 0;
j =+ k;
```

Comment: I'd say, it is the same as `j = +k`. So, `=+` is not an operator, it is poor formatting.

Comment: There is already a question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939023/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: This reminds me of the question about the C++ long-arrow operator: `for (int i = 10; i --> 0;) { }` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a comparison operator, it is simple assignment. You are just adding a sign to your variable. If you added a `-`, it would negate it.

Comment: Yes, two operators, only looking as one.

Answer (score 0):

Also another important aspect of the combined operators like =+ or =- is the fact they add an implicit cast. This is vital when you are doing operations on bytes (for example). \

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 2;

a += b; //this is valid add operation
```

Note: the sum of two bytes is an int value, unless you do a cast.

```
a =(byte) a + b //but with the compound assignment you dont have to include the cast.
```